# PDF declared as record throws error when clicked to open

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have a PDF which is declared a record in a SP 2013 docs library. When i click on this document to open the pdf, it throws following error:

[image]

The error message is consistent between different SharePoint sites, farms and PDF documents. I was also able to reproduce this error by manually declaring a document a record and then open it by clicking on it.

Any ideas why this happens and how may this be avoided.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is not considered an error it's information message that told you can 't make any changes to this document because it's checked out by another user.

**To avoid this message :**

- Check the user who checks out this document and asks him to check it back in.
- Log in as administrator and undo check out to can be editable for all users base on their permission.

**To remove the requirement to check out files**

- Navigate to the library you plan to work in. If the library name does not appear in the Quick Launch pane, click All Site Content, and then select the name of your library.
- On the ribbon, in the Library Tools group, click the Library tab.
- Click Library Settings  Library Settings button on the SharePoint Foundation Library ribbon .
- On the Library Settings page, under General Settings, click Versioning settings.
- In the Require Check Out section, under the Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited? question, select No.

[image]

- Click OK to close the dialog box and return to the Library Settings page.

Read more [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-a-site-library-to-require-check-out-of-files-f63fcbdc-1db6-4eb7-a3eb-dd815500c9e7)

Comment: I think the key information is that the document has just been declared a record, and after that the message appears, not that it is checked out to a specific user